# Qt's std::unordered_set analogue/counterpart

Tags: c++, qt, containers, unordered-set

*Qt*'s counterpart for ordered associative container `std::map` is `QMap`, `std::set` is `QSet`, for unordered associative container `std::unordered_map` is `QHash`.

What should I use to replace `std::unordered_set` in *Qt*? There is neither `QHash< T, void >` specialization, nor `QHash< T >`.

Is there planned analogue?

Comment: @NathanOliver Many people appreciate a (good) code style. This term, I think, includes uniformity. Qt is almost self-contained library (at least it want to be). I prefer to use Qt-specific items, if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`QSet`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qset.html) is actually Qt's version of `std::unordered_set`.  What Qt doesn't have is an analog to `std::set`.

Comment: `QSet` is unordered?

Comment: @Orient Yes.  From the link in the answer: *QSet<T> is one of Qt's generic container classes. It stores values in an unspecified order and provides very fast lookup of the values. Internally, QSet<T> is implemented as a QHash.*

Comment: Another fun fact is `QList` is not Qt's version of `std::list`.  That is `QLinkedList`

Comment: `QList` is `std::deque`?

Comment: @Orient It looks that way but I can't say for certain.  I don't know if it would fit the standard's definition.

Comment: @Orient, You might be interested in [this comparision](https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/) between the standard containers and their Qt analogues...

Comment: Well, it is ordered, but the order is arbitrary. With they'd use "sorted" rather than "ordered".